# Find substrings in a set of strings

Tags: python, string, set, substring

I have a large (50k-100k) set of strings `mystrings`. Some of the strings in `mystrings` may be exact substrings of others, and I would like to collapse these (discard the substring and only keep the longest). Right now I'm using a naive method, which has `O(N^2)` complexity.

```
unique_strings = set()
for s in sorted(mystrings, key=len, reverse=True):
    keep = True
    for us in unique_strings:
        if s in us:
            keep = False
            break
    if keep:
        unique_strings.add(s)
```

Which data structures or algorithms would make this task easier and not require `O(N^2)` operations. Libraries are ok, but I need to stay pure Python.

Comment: More Pythonic, discard the `keep` boolean and use an `else` clause on the `for` loop instead (won't change time complexity of course) http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html

Comment: @Chris_Rands Could you demonstrate? There's no reason to continue iterating over the inner for loop once a match is found, thus the break. But then, once we're out of the inner loop we don't know if we broke out because a match was found or if we're just finished iterating. Maybe I'm missing something, but I think this is the most concise and performant way to implement this (admittedly naive) approach.

Comment: You keep the `break`, just replace `if keep:` with `else:` (same indentation) and remove all lines with `keep`. The `else` clause is only executed when the `break` does not occur. read the article I linked above if you're not familiar with the for-else construct

Comment: Cool! The keywords are so common I overlooked the semantic implications for loops.

Comment: In fact, looking again, you could use `any()` or `all()` instead, like `if not any(s in us for us in unique_strings): unique_strings.add(s)` It will short-circuit like with `break`

Answer (score 1):

Finding a substring in a set():

```py
name = set()
name.add('Victoria Stuart')                         ## add single element
name.update(('Carmine Wilson', 'Jazz', 'Georgio'))  ## add multiple elements
name
{'Jazz', 'Georgio', 'Carmine Wilson', 'Victoria Stuart'}

me = 'Victoria'
if str(name).find(me):
    print('{} in {}'.format(me, name))
# Victoria in {'Jazz', 'Georgio', 'Carmine Wilson', 'Victoria Stuart'}
```

That's pretty easy -- but somewhat problematic, if you want to return the matching string:

```py
for item in name:
    if item.find(me):
            print(item)
'''
Jazz
Georgio
Carmine Wilson
'''

print(str(name).find(me))
# 39    ## character offset for match (i.e., not a string)
```

As you can see, the loop above only executes *until* the condition is `True`, terminating before printing the item we want (the matching string).

It's probably better, easier to use regex (regular expressions):

```py
import re

for item in name:
    if re.match(me, item):
            full_name = item
            print(item)
# Victoria Stuart
print(full_name)
# Victoria Stuart

for item in name:
    if re.search(me, item):
            print(item)
# Victoria Stuart
```

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> **search() vs. match()**
>
> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string ...

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach:

```
1. sort strings by length, longest first  # `O(N*log_N)`
2. foreach string:  # O(N)
    3. insert each suffix into tree structure: first letter -> root, and so on.  
       # O(L) or O(L^2) depending on string slice implementation, L: string length
    4. if inserting the entire string (the longest suffix) creates a new 
       leaf node, keep it!

O[N*(log_N + L)]  or  O[N*(log_N + L^2)]
```

This is probably far from optimal, but should be significantly better than `O(N^2)` for large `N` (number of strings) and small `L` (average string length).

You could also iterate through the strings in descending order by length and add all substrings of each string to a set, and only keep those strings that are not in the set. The algorithmic big O should be the same as for the worse case above (`O[N*(log_N + L^2)]`), but the implementation is much simpler:

```
seen_strings, keep_strings = set(), set()
for s in sorted(mystrings, key=len, reverse=True):
    if s not in seen_strings:
        keep_strings.add(s)
        l = len(s)
        for start in range(0, l-1):
            for end in range(start+1, l):
                seen_strings.add(s[start:end])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I came up with this approach.

```
from Bio.trie import trie
unique_strings = set()
suffix_tree = trie()
for s in sorted(mystrings, key=len, reverse=True):
    if suffix_tree.with_prefix(contig) == []:
        unique_strings.add(s)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            suffix_tree[s[i:]] = 1
```

**The good**: ≈15 minutes --> ≈20 seconds for the data set I was working with. **The bad**: introduces `biopython` as a dependency, which is neither lightweight nor pure python (as I originally asked).

Answer (score 0):

You can presort the strings and create a dictionary that maps strings to positions in the sorted list. Then you can loop over the list of strings (O(N)) and suffixes (O(L)) and set those entries to `None` that exist in the position-dict (O(1) dict lookup and O(1) list update). So in total this has O(N*L) complexity where `L` is the average string length.

```
strings = sorted(mystrings, key=len, reverse=True)
index_map = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(strings)}
unique = set()
for i, s in enumerate(strings):
    if s is None:
        continue
    unique.add(s)
    for k in range(1, len(s)):
        try:
            index = index_map[s[k:]]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            if strings[index] is None:
                break
            strings[index] = None
```

Testing on the following sample data gives a speedup factor of about 21:

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase

mystrings = [''.join(random.choices(ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(1, 10)))
             for __ in range(1000)]
mystrings = set(mystrings)
```